# как убрать пробелы со знаками новой строки в списке

Tags: python, файлы, циклы

при использовании

```py
line.splitlines()
lines = file.readlines ()
for z in lines :
    for z in range(int(z)+1)
```

выдаёт:

> ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0 0 0 1 0 0 0\n'

Comment: `z.rstrip('\n')`

Comment: Тут надо не пробелы убирать, а радикально править код.

Comment: а что вы вообще хотите сделать этим стрёмным кодом?